# Interchange order of integration

Tags: integration

Can you help me guys? I need to intercahnge order of integration here:
$$
\int_1^2dx \int_{2-x}^{\sqrt{2x-x^{2}}}f(x,y)dy
$$
Thank you so much.

Comment: If you expect us to take the time to craft a thoughtful answer, please take the time to copy the details of your question into your post.

Comment: Hi welcome to mse. Please consider writing your post using mathjax. Also, will you mind sharing with us what have you tried so far? For this type of problems doing a picture of the region of integration is really useful.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín I think you have changed the limits of integration from the original post.

Comment: @DougM thanks. It now looks exactly as the image posted by the OP.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Read this for help with asking questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plot the graph $x=1$, $x=2$, $y=2-x$ and $y=\sqrt{2x-x^2}$ and mark the bounded area.

[image]

solve $y=\sqrt{2x-x^2}$ to get $x=1\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}$ but $x\in[1,2]$ therefore take $x=1+\sqrt{1-y^2}$

take the horizontal rectangular slab in the bounded area. The integral becomes

$$\int_1^2dx \int_{2-x}^{\sqrt{2x-x^{2}}}f(x,y)dy=\int_{y=0}^{y=1} dy\int_{x=2-y}^{x=1+\sqrt{1-y^2}}f(x,y)\ dx$$